# Discrepancy between using forward vs. backslash in Linux emulator on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, perl

So I've run into quite the problem that I have no idea how to solve. I'm using the Cygwin Linux emulator on a Windows computer to do some molecular dynamics simulations that are written in perl. I've been running into the issue where I am unable to read a file. The code that is the problem is here:

```
if (defined $topfile && -r $topfile) {
  $self->_sendCommand("open unit 10 read form name \"$topfile\"");
  $self->_sendCommand("read RTF card unit 10");
  $self->_sendCommand("close unit 10");
  $havertf=1;
}
```

I've tested it using the following:

```
print "$topfile\n";
if (-r $topfile) {
  print "YES\n";
}
if (defined $topfile) {
  print "YES2\n";
}
```

So both YES statements print and I know that the file is defined and readable.

I tested print statements for each line of the first part and my problem appears after "open unit 10 read form name." 
Here is the exact error:

```
 CHARMM>    open unit 10 read form name /C:/CHARMM_Nichols/CHARMM/test/data/top_all22_prot.inp/
 VOPEN> Attempting to open::/c:/charmm_nichols/charmm/test/data/top_all22_prot.inp/::
 OPNLGU> Unit  10 cannot be opened as /C:/CHARMM_NICHOLS/CHARMM/TEST/DATA/TOP_ALL22_PROT.INP/
```

I think the issue comes down to backslashes vs forwardslashes, as all of my directories are in a windows system (backslashes), but the programs are executing expecting a Linux system (forward slashes). Any idea how to fix and/or test this? Could I write a script to change the forward to backslashes? It won't let me change my environment variable ($topfile) to be backslashes in the emulator.

Comment: Why did you add the leading and trailing forward slash?  Does removing them fix the problem?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't fix it :( I should be clear that this is someone else's script that I'm just trying to get to work on my system. I'm not sure why they added the slashes though

Comment: Some of the POSIX/Windows path conversions are done by the cygwin layer. In your case it looks like the files are searched under `/c:/..` but cygwin normally maps `c:/` to `/` or `/cygdrive/c` so its - probably - something else wrecking the filenames. You could try to create a symbolic link as dirty trick like `ln -s /cygdrive/c '/c:'` or copy/link your data to the "home" ~ and use relative path names if possible.

Comment: You're my hero! Changing the env variable to /cygdrive/c/ seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!!!